# Xen dom0 and domu ifconfig returns different stats

Tags: virtualization, xen, ifconfig, diff, stat

I expected that when I use ifconfig command to display network traffic RX and TX values both for dom0 and domu machine,
there are differences.

I run once ping inside the domu.

domu ifconfig command show

```
[root@localhost /]# ifconfig eth0 | grep bytes
        RX packets 705  bytes 55860 (54.5 KiB)
        TX packets 521  bytes 65074 (63.5 KiB)
[root@localhost /]# ping robtex.com
PING robtex.com (79.125.4.106) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ec2-79-125-4-106.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (79.125.4.106): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=28.1 ms
--- robtex.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 28.102/28.102/28.102/0.000 ms
[root@localhost /]# ifconfig eth0 | grep bytes
        RX packets 710  bytes 56205 (54.8 KiB)
        TX packets 526  bytes 65411 (63.8 KiB)
[root@localhost /]#
```

on CentOS, dom0 ifconfig command show

```
[root@CentOS-58-64-minimal [/]# ifconfig vif33.0  | grep bytes
          RX bytes:57780 (56.4 KiB)  TX bytes:65730 (64.1 KiB)
[root@CentOS-58-64-minimal [/]# ifconfig vif33.0  | grep bytes
          RX bytes:58047 (56.6 KiB)  TX bytes:66145 (64.5 KiB)
[root@CentOS-58-64-minimal [/]#
```

May be someone can explain me why those differencies

dom0

RX 58047 - 57780 => 267
TX 66145 - 65730 => 415

domu

RX 56205 - 55860 => 345
TX 65411 - 65074 => 337

Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Don't judge simply by byte count or packet count — keep `tcpdump` running on both Dom0 and DomU, and you'll probably see that another non-IP traffic travels in each domain specifically.